# read() not working properly

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, io

I am trying to read a txt file using read() and print out the output.

the text file has these numbers:

```
123
456 
227
```

and my code is shown below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include<io.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    char* input;
    char* output;
    int fd;
    int temp = 0;




if(argc != 3){
        printf("Too Many or Too Few Arguments\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    input = argv[1];
    output = argv[2];

    fd = open(input,O_RDONLY,0);
    if(fd == -1){
        printf("Read Failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
    while(read(fd, &temp ,sizeof(int)) != 0){
        printf("%d\n", temp);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

I tried running it and this is the output

```
221458993
909456394
842150410
842150455
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `read` does not convert text to binary. What you want is `fscanf` (or `fgets` with your own parsing).

Comment: 221458993 is the decimal representation of the bytes of the first line, which in hex is 0D333231, and converted to ASCII = "\n321"

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform `formatted I/O` to get the `int` value representation.

[`fscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fsanf) or better, [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) is your friend.